# C# Service trouble with video outputs in Desktop Duplication API

Tags: c#, c++, dll, windows-services, desktop-duplication

I use the **C# Service** for calling the **Desktop Duplication API** from **C++ DLL functions** and it works correct whenever i **use this DLL in C++ projects or C#** for DLL functions calls. But there is some trouble when **EnumOutputs** function, of **IDXGIAdapter1** COM object, is used by call **from the C# Service**: EnumOutputs **can't detect any video output** on any video adapater. I have used different log on user of service: system user, system user with permission to interact with desktop and admin, but none of this worked.

What could be reason of this problem?

I write info in the DLL function, that used **EnumOutputs** function, to an txt file and it shows me this:

[image: Output info from DLL function that calls the **EnumOutput** function]

Comment: Are you still working on this project?